# ':processDebugResources'. > java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1' Gradle error

Tags: java, android, gradle

Getting ':processDebugResources'. > java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1'while Gradle project sync after moving Gradle version from 2.14 to 4.4

Below is some log snippet :

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':nuswype
dev:processDebugResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
```

This issue is appearing when I am trying to sync project after upgrading gradle i.e., making changes in gradle plugin version and distribution URL :|

Build Logs snippet from console:

```
11:03:00.818 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT warning(542041398), Job(QueuedJob{
title=Linking, 
task={config=AaptPackageConfig(manifestFile=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml, options=AaptOptions(noCompress=null, failOnMissingConfigEntry=false, additionalParameters=null), androidJarPath=C:\tools\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar, variantType=DEFAULT, sourceOutputDir=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\generated\source\r\debug, resourceOutputApk=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_, librarySymbolTableFiles=[C:\Code\Test\reslib\build\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\d30f6a41a3493ed94e0db001717dee9d\339afdfa22f49f1269b39407a6f4c298\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Code\Test\corelib\build\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aa26708d27f3d5c7cf51cf24f8986b1b\1dc9d34cf009bfe0712a7075536cea9b\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\7f0f7479b516dcb23023411daa5520cd\c20a57f8dd37ce3db17e37afe01532f1\package-aware-r.txt], symbolOutputDir=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\symbols\debug, verbose=false, resourceDirs=[C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug], proguardOutputFile=null, mainDexListProguardOutputFile=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt, splits=[], debuggable=true, customPackageForR=com.nuance.swype.input.ime, pseudoLocalize=false, preferredDensity=null, resourceConfigs=[], generateProtos=false, imports=[], packageId=null, dependentFeatures=[], listResourceFiles=false, staticLibrary=false, staticLibraryDependencies=[], intermediateDir=null)}, 
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@5bbe60ac}): C:\Code\Test\reslib\build\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\layout\checkbox_icon_preference.xml:3: warn: generated id 'android:id/widget_frame' for external package 'android'.
11:03:04.267 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT1 err(Facade for 233221396): Done -> QueuedJob{
title=Linking, 
task={config=AaptPackageConfig(manifestFile=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml, options=AaptOptions(noCompress=null, failOnMissingConfigEntry=false, additionalParameters=null), androidJarPath=C:\tools\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar, variantType=DEFAULT, sourceOutputDir=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\generated\source\r\debug, resourceOutputApk=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_, librarySymbolTableFiles=[C:\Code\Test\reslib\build\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\d30f6a41a3493ed94e0db001717dee9d\339afdfa22f49f1269b39407a6f4c298\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Code\Test\corelib\build\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aa26708d27f3d5c7cf51cf24f8986b1b\1dc9d34cf009bfe0712a7075536cea9b\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\9d14b253953a67224aed1a196311ae2f\0548ec7a53ea7ab370aed068852b161b\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\7f0f7479b516dcb23023411daa5520cd\c20a57f8dd37ce3db17e37afe01532f1\package-aware-r.txt], symbolOutputDir=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\symbols\debug, verbose=false, resourceDirs=[C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug], proguardOutputFile=null, mainDexListProguardOutputFile=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt, splits=[], debuggable=true, customPackageForR=com.nuance.swype.input.ime, pseudoLocalize=false, preferredDensity=null, resourceConfigs=[], generateProtos=false, imports=[], packageId=null, dependentFeatures=[], listResourceFiles=false, staticLibrary=false, staticLibraryDependencies=[], intermediateDir=null)}, 
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@5bbe60ac}
11:03:04.267 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT warning(542041398), Job(QueuedJob{
title=Linking, 
task={config=AaptPackageConfig(manifestFile=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml, options=AaptOptions(noCompress=null, failOnMissingConfigEntry=false, additionalParameters=null), androidJarPath=C:\tools\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar, variantType=DEFAULT, sourceOutputDir=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\generated\source\r\debug, resourceOutputApk=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_, librarySymbolTableFiles=[C:\Code\Test\reslib\build\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\d30f6a41a3493ed94e0db001717dee9d\339afdfa22f49f1269b39407a6f4c298\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Code\Test\corelib\build\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt,  C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\9d14b253953a67224aed1a196311ae2f\0548ec7a53ea7ab370aed068852b161b\package-aware-r.txt, C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\7f0f7479b516dcb23023411daa5520cd\c20a57f8dd37ce3db17e37afe01532f1\package-aware-r.txt], symbolOutputDir=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\symbols\debug, verbose=false, resourceDirs=[C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug], proguardOutputFile=null, mainDexListProguardOutputFile=C:\Code\Test\nuswypedev\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt, splits=[], debuggable=true, customPackageForR=com.nuance.swype.input.ime, pseudoLocalize=false, preferredDensity=null, resourceConfigs=[], generateProtos=false, imports=[], packageId=null, dependentFeatures=[], listResourceFiles=false, staticLibrary=false, staticLibraryDependencies=[], intermediateDir=null)}, 
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@5bbe60ac}): Done
11:03:04.308 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_8): Death requested
11:03:04.308 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_7): Death requested
11:03:04.308 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_7): destruction
11:03:04.308 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_5): Death requested
11:03:04.308 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_5): destruction
11:03:04.308 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_8): destruction
11:03:04.308 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_6): Death requested
11:03:04.309 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_6): destruction
11:03:04.313 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Process (469795084) processed 0 files
11:03:04.313 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_8): Process(469795084), after shutdown queue_size=3
11:03:04.315 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Process (186846505) processed 0 files
11:03:04.315 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_7): Process(186846505), after shutdown queue_size=2
11:03:04.320 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Process (233221396) processed 1 files
11:03:04.320 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_5): Process(233221396), after shutdown queue_size=1
11:03:04.321 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Process (882946521) processed 0 files
11:03:04.322 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(queued-resource-processor_6): Process(882946521), after shutdown queue_size=0
11:03:04.327 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Shutdown finished in 20ms
11:03:04.327 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute taskAction for :nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.328 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] Snapshotting property incrementalFolder (OUTPUT) for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.330 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] Snapshotting property mainDexListProguardOutputFile (OUTPUT) for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.335 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] Snapshotting property resPackageOutputFolder (OUTPUT) for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.387 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] Snapshotting property sourceOutputDir (OUTPUT) for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.398 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] Snapshotting property symbolslWithPackageNameOutputFile (OUTPUT) for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.399 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] Snapshotting property textSymbolOutputFile (OUTPUT) for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.403 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] No discovered inputs for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.403 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
11:03:04.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.404 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :nuswypedev:processDebugResources FAILED
11:03:04.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :nuswypedev:processDebugResources'
11:03:04.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :nuswypedev:processDebugResources' completed
11:03:04.404 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :nuswypedev:processDebugResources (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 10.316 secs.
11:03:04.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.11 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
11:03:04.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':' Thread 3: released lock on root.1.11
11:03:04.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':' Thread 3: released lock on :
11:03:04.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 27.243 secs, idle: 3.069 secs
11:03:04.408 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
11:03:04.418 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 35 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 28 up-to-date
11:03:04.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
11:03:04.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on root.1
11:03:04.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
11:03:04.464 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for task history cache (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\4.4\taskHistory)
11:03:04.464 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskHistory.bin (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\4.4\taskHistory\taskHistory.bin)
11:03:04.465 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\4.4\taskHistory).
11:03:04.468 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Build Output Cleanup Cache (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup)
11:03:04.468 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache outputFiles.bin (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup\outputFiles.bin)
11:03:04.469 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Build Output Cleanup Cache (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup).
11:03:04.472 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
11:03:04.473 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
11:03:04.478 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 6 resolution results binary files in 0.008 secs
11:03:04.629 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
11:03:04.629 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
11:03:04.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Artifact transforms cache (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1)
11:03:04.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache results.bin (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\metadata-1.1\results.bin)
11:03:04.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Artifact transforms cache (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\transforms-1).
11:03:04.635 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes)
11:03:04.635 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes\fileHashes.bin)
11:03:04.635 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (C:\Code\Test\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes).
11:03:04.636 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Generated Gradle JARs cache (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\4.4\generated-gradle-jars) was closed 0 times.
11:03:04.643 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for artifact cache (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\modules-2)
11:03:04.643 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifact.bin (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-artifact.bin)
11:03:04.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifacts.bin (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-artifacts.bin)
11:03:04.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-metadata.bin)
11:03:04.656 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-versions.bin (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-versions.bin)
11:03:04.659 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
11:03:04.660 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
11:03:04.741 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@225a4c38
11:03:04.741 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 18: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
11:03:04.743 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=8948, address=[06f0ea6b-fc4b-4bcc-bfec-189dca7409df port:65210, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Busy, lastBusy=1536211939502, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=c2d60ef4-3c27-44ac-ac54-826265952316,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Shubham_Prakash\.gradle\daemon,pid=8948,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
11:03:04.743 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
11:03:04.745 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop

11:03:04.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:03:04.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:03:04.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:03:04.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] *What went wrong:
11:03:04.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'.
11:03:04.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] >java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
11:03:04.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:03:04.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] *Try:
11:03:04.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
11:03:04.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:03:04.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] *Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
11:03:04.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
11:03:04.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 52s
```

Comment: Can you include the build log? You can run in the project directory "gradlew :nuswypedev:processDebugResources" and post the output here.

Comment: Updated the build logs, Thanks.

Comment: Hmm this isn't the full log. Can you run "cradles :nuswypedev:processDebugResources --debug" in the projects directory and post the output?

Comment: I have updated the logs with debug info, however due to size limitation I could paste only few snippet.

Comment: There should be an AAPT error in the logs from when the resource linking fails. Make sure you check the std err not just std out. It should be visible if you just run without "--debug" too.

Comment: What type of AAPT error would be present in the logs? I am not clear about the comments.

Comment: It will say "Error: <file path> <file line> : <error message>. It will tell you which file is causing the failure and how to fix it.

Comment: I ran build command with -debug but couldn't get any information as you said there was no line no., below are the error logs :

[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
  [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'.
 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] >java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1